# The drywall under a window looks gouged, what are my next steps?

Tags: water-damage, patching-drywall

We had a leak about 8 months ago on our roof, which a roofer addressed sealed with silicone.  I very recently found the damage in the below images. It's between a windowsill that is about one inch from the baseboards, and the baseboards themselves.  I touched it and it was bone dry and crumbly. The top object is the windowsills and the bottom object is the baseboards.

It doesn't look like water damage I've seen, but I could be wrong.
Any ideas about causes and remedies, and which kind of professional to call in?
[image: Picture One]
[image: Picture Two]

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at due to the extreme closeup scope of the images, but the drywall looks fine. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

That's *exactly* what drywall looks like when it's cut and "bone dry and crumbly" is *exactly* what you want from your drywall. Usually cut edges are hidden behind trim or butted up against another sheet of drywall (if in the middle of a wall/ceiling) then covered with tape (drywall joint "tape") and mud (drywall joint compound) so they're no longer visible.

Normally, the window trim would cover the top cut edge of the drywall and the baseboard would cover the bottom cut edge of the drywall. In this case, it seems that you have a *very* low window that comes down to just above the baseboard. For some reason, the drywall doesn't seem to have gone from the floor to just below the window in one continuous piece, and they skipped out on the mud job, too.

**TL;DR:** This is *nothing* to worry about in terms of water damage from your leaky roof.

It's *possibly* a sign that the home builder used the absolute lowest cost workers/sub-contractors and didn't care much about getting the details right. This *might* mean that other short cuts were taken. However, *in theory* the building inspections that had to be completed should have caught any serious issues and those would have been rectified. The only one inspecting the drywall job would have been the original owner.

---

I am mildly concerned about your roofer addressing a leak with "just silicone". However, if you have concerns, that would be the subject of a whole new question that would need to include pictures of the area in question.